# SQL: Proving a pattern with time

Tags: sql

I have the following query trying to prove a pattern that:

Transactions/bills  cannot be issued  at times when the given bar is closed:

SQL Query:

```
select t.transactionID, t.drinker, t.time, b.bar, b.closeTime
from transactions t 
inner join bars b 
on t.bar=b.bar  
where t.time>b.closeTime;
```

The problem is that some there are two restaurants in the bar table. Each with a different closeTime. Therefore, as a result:  With 
transactionID drinker, time, bar, and closetime

```
   00001                     Kate             22:04.       oysterbar    24 
   00001                     Kate.            22:04.       oysterbar.   2
```

The issue is that I do not want to have two of the same things. Because of joins and there are two oysterbar in the bars table with different closetime. I want to print out the first transaction id 00001 and not two 00001 because the second oysterbar has a different closing time.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two issues.

1. First, from your sample output, it appears you have a data quality
       issue.  Your "restaurants" actually have unique keys (`oysterbar` vs
       `oysterbar.`), but the transaction data is duplicated.
2. The other
       issue I see is with the query itself.  The closing time predicate is
       almost certainly not doing what you expect, particularly making the
       inference that you are trying to capture after-hours transactions.  Ideally, you would compare the transaction time to the
   period
           between closing and opening times.  Your two rows above are perfect
           examples: at 10:04 pm you have a transaction and of the two
           restaurants one closes at 2 am and the other at (I guess) midnight. 
           Both are in all likelihood still open at the time of the
           transaction.

FWIW a nicer query re: issue #2 could be:

```
select t.transactionID, t.drinker, t.time, b.bar, b.closeTime
from transactions t 
inner join bars b 
on t.bar=b.bar  
where t.time BETWEEN b.openTime AND b.closeTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work;

```
select t.transactionID, t.drinker, t.time, t.bar, j.closeTime
from transactions t 
inner join (
select t1.transactionID, min(b1.closeTime) closeTime
from transactions t1 
inner join bars b1
on t1.bar=b1.bar  
where t1.time>b1.closeTime
group by t1.transactionId) j
on t.transactionID = j.transactionID;
```